# How can I make the length decrease constant between each object when using array modifier and object offset?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

I'm trying to make a wicker weave for a chair I'm modelling, and am using an array modifier with object offset to model part of it. The issue is that the step size between each instance of the array isn't constant, so I'm getting this exponential looking curve at the edge, when what I really need is closer to a straight line (which I've annotated in the attached screenshot). If anyone has any idea how to make the step size constant or knows an alternative way of doing this, that would be much appreciated! Thanks, Rowan

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/25944/2214

Comment: I wanted to offer Dupliframes https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliframes.html , but this feature was lost in 2.8+ ... But Animation nodes could be an alternative for you https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/136670/2214 or in this time also Geometry nodes ?

Comment: Hi vklidu, thanks for your answer. I did see the post about the pyramid generator, is it possible to use custom objects with it, rather than the standard cuboid it uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 2.79

Natively in 2.79 you can use **[Dupliframes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliframes.html)** under 2.79 for this step. Create first keyframe, last keyframe of location and scale and enable under *Object Properties > Duplication >* **Frames**

[image]

Or you can use [script (by Chebhou)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/25952/2214). It generates separated objects, that shares the same object data, so you can easily edit original data (shape) to affect all those objects or simply change object data to completely different one. Like if script generates a cube you can switch to Torus object data or what ever under Data Properties. But I see script works in 2.79 ...

### 2.9+

For 2.9x you would have to use something like **Animation Nodes** like [Ligazeton's example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/136670/2214). Or probably in experimental build you can try *Geometry Nodes*.