# "Instance on Points" node connection with a mesh function of the index?

Tags: geometry-nodes

*(Using Blender 3.6.5)*

> To save your time, notice that similar questions were already posted with detailed answers. Here are some well documented resources:
> (1) [Why is there a red line when I try to connect one node to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557/why-is-there-a-red-line-when-i-try-to-connect-one-node-to-another)
> (2) [Why can't the radius of an Icosphere be set depending on position with geometry nodes [SOLVED]](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/280188/why-cant-the-radius-of-an-icosphere-be-set-depending-on-position-with-geometry)
> (3) [How can I instantiate a procedural node group with different parameters?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274485/how-can-i-instantiate-a-procedural-node-group-with-different-parameters)

Exploring different approaches to answer J.A.'s question [Is it possible to have an equivalent of Array modifier with decreasing count?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/308858), and after reading [Markus von Broady's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/308879/177431) based on extrusion, I played with the idea of preparing different floors for the tower then of stacking these with an *Instance on Points* node, instead of stacking the same floor (a circle), then of changing the shape (i.e. the number of bricks per circle). To do so, I planned to use the *Pick Instance* socket.
It works fine with a static collection made using a *Geometry to Instance* node connected to pre-made shapes (see the top of the GN graph in the figure).
But I am failing in creating shapes using a function based on the vertices index (see the middle part of the GN graph in the figure). The value downstream of the *Sample Index* node is correct in a *Viewer* node, but there is an error connecting it as input to the *Mesh Circle* node. I am suspecting that along the data path of this branch, there is a conflict between the geometry requirements flowing backward from the *Instance* socket, and the geometry information flowing forward from the *Mesh Line* node.
Am I trying to do something that is orthogonal to GN philosophy ? Or am I missing something ?

[image: GN graph]

Resources: [image]

Comment: the problem is "just" the difference between a single value (circular input) and a field value (diamond shaped input). The sample index has a diamond as output (so it is a field value), but Mesh circle vertices input is a field value - that's why you cannot connect them.

Comment: Shame in me ! I missed this... I was clearly trying something breaking rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure there's plenty similar questions to that, perhaps even it can be closed as a duplicate, but I think it's easier to answer than to find the other question…

The *Mesh Circle* node, just like most (exception: "Points" node) other "geometry primitive" nodes, creates just a single primitive.

So that's how the node is programmed, it creates a single "circle" (regular polygon really). It doesn't then make sense to use a field to control the number of vertices of this "circle". In case of a radius, you could at least argue that you want a "loop", which has a varying radius, just like the 3D equivalent I call a geoide under the link below:

[Why can't the radius of an Icosphere be set depending on position with geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/280194/60486)

There's various tricks you can employ to create multiple "circles" with varying resolution, for example you can duplicate one circle and resample each spline differently:

[image]

[image]

Repeat Zone equivalent (well, the positioning isn't the same, for simplicity):

[image]