# How to generate a different ID for each instance made using the "Instance on points" node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to distribute Bezier curves on a surface of an object using geo nodes (as in the pictures below).
But when I tried to randomize their properties, it didn't work unless I provided a constant ID number. How can I generate a unique ID for every instance so that each curve is different?

[image: Random Value>Bezier Segment> Instance on points does not work ;(]

[image: It works when I provide a constant ID]

By the way, sorry if the question is dumb, I'm new to geometry nodes :P

Comment: May I recommend to read the links referenced at the top of this (very similar) question: ["Instance on Points" node connection with a mesh function of the index?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/308889) ?

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't fully answer your question, but one option is to make a bunch of different looking instances and bundle them together for the Instance on Points' use.

Like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want fully randomized end points, you can convert some mesh line instances to curves and use noise to randomize them. Use spline parameter to randomize only their tops or bottoms, perhaps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*(Using Blender 3.6.5)*

Instances are made to save resources by sharing the same mesh (i.e. points position relative to origin of the instanced object, points/edges/faces connectivity, ...). Only few and global parameters such as origin position in world coordinates, scaling and rotation are specific to each instance, and thus can be randomized. *Instances* with different shapes/meshes do not fit in this concept.
To achieve full random shape variations of a reference object, a *Duplicate Elements* node is useful as it provides the *Duplicate Index* that can be used to "iterate" over copies and to apply individual modifications.

The following Geometry Nodes graph mimics what seems expected from posted views, using *Duplicate Elements* instead of *Instance on Points* node. Beware that the resources cost is high, and that approaches such as the one detailed in ["How can I instantiate a procedural node group with different parameters?"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274485/how-can-i-instantiate-a-procedural-node-group-with-different-parameters) might be better.

[image: GN graph]

**1.** A generic *Bezier Segment* is duplicated as many times as there are points in the input geometry (a simple 5x5 grid for the demonstration purpose).
**2.** Each copy position is shifted by the point position, from the input geometry, sharing the same *Index*. This position is recovered with a *Sample Index* node set in *Point* domain.
**3.** The *End Handle* to randomize is carried by the *End* control point of each curve. Those points have odd indexes. Such indexes are recovered by multiply by 2 (i.e. the count of control points per curve) the copy index plus 1.
**4.** A random offset, with *Seed* set to the copy index, is applied to the left handle by a *Set Handle Positions* node (NB: the right handle position is automatically updated for [Aligned handles](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/modeling/curves/structure.html#curve-bezier-handle-type)).

**Resources:** [image]