# How to Select every other Edge in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I need to make this edge selection in geometry nodes, so that I can move the selected edges away from each other.

I need to be able to add/subtract edges (by adding more vertices in the Grid node) so the selection needs to be dynamic.

[image]

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.5)*

Here is a proposal assuming that the object to transform is a Cartesian grid in (X,Y) plane, and that the edges to select are at constant Y coordinate. It does not rely on the vertices index.

[image: GN graph]

**1.** The sub-graph made of nodes *Edge Vertices*, *Subtract* and *Multiply* is computing a selection mask that is different from 0 only for edges aligned with Y axis, because of the multiplication by vector (0,1,0).
**2.** The *Inverted* output geometry of the *Separate Geometry* node is then the edges aligned with X Axis. These are transformed to curves, one per horizontal sequence of edges.
**3.** The sub-graph made of nodes *Index*, *Modulo* and *Equal* is computing a selection mask that is *true* for even curves index. This is stored in a *Named Attribute* named *even*.
**4.** Curves are transformed back to edges and the *Named Attribute* is transferred to the vertices.
**5.** Both separated geometries are joined back and vertices are merged by distance. The *Named Attribute* is preserved.
**6.** The *Named Attribute* is input as a selection mask in the *Set Position* node to offset the position of *even* vertices only.

**Resources:**

- Inspiration for the selection mask of specific edges: see  Markus von Broady's answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/308879/177431).
- Blender file: [image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I haven't had time to get back and try this solution but it looks legit so I'm marking it as correct. Once I revisit this in closer detail I will report back if there is a problem.

Answer (score 5):

try this setup:

[image]

Note: this works in your case because you have an even number of vertices in vertical.

Note2: this moves "in reality" the vertices - but the "right" ones so this should be what you want

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind explaining what the Floored Modulo node is doing?

Comment: Also, the problem with this method is that whenever I end up with an odd number of pairs, the selection changes and the object becomes symmetric, which won't work for me in this case :(