# How can I select edge loops in a mesh using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, edges

In my scenario, I have a few stacks of edge loops bridged together and am seeking a way to select a specified loop using geometry nodes to perform transformations on.

A mesh I am working on which contains 6 horizontal loops with 600 vertices per loop. I want to be able to feed each selected loop through transformation nodes I have implemented (gif animation)[image: Sample Mesh]

[image: Vertex Transformation]

Comment: You could select your loops based on z-position. Did you try it ?

Comment: May I suggest to read this post: [How to Select every other Edge in Geometry Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/308909/how-to-select-every-other-edge-in-geometry-nodes) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Select every other Edge in Geometry Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/308909/how-to-select-every-other-edge-in-geometry-nodes)

Comment: It's a bit unclear at what stage you want to make the selection.. would something [along these lines](https://imgur.com/a/OOLWIrj) do it for you?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I have only tried selecting by Z-position so far but get strange results when plugging it into the vertex transformation. However, I will investigate and try again and also give the other solutions a shot this week